# What is the meaning of "until the seven dreadful bells when I was supposed to be at the church"?

Tags: meaning

> I  could  not  sleep  because  of  a  presentiment  of  something  irremediable.  In  the  middle  of  the  night  I 
>   began to count the passage of the hours on the cathedral clock, until the seven dreadful bells when I was supposed 
>   to  be  at  the  church.  - (Garcia Marquez, Memories of my melancholy whores)

Does the author mean 7 am by saying "seven dreadful bells" or he says that bell was rung seven times? How does the bell work for a wedding?

Comment: Yes, "seven bells" (on land, anyway) means "a bell was rung 7 times, indicating we had passed into the 7th hour of the day". Now, we'd have to read the broader passage to know whether the church adhered to the old practice of ringing actual, physical, bells, or whether it was used in a more metaphorical sense meaning simply "7 am", however he determined that (e.g. by reading the face of the clock in the cathedral's tower). Note that on a ship's watch (i.e. at sea), *bell* still means "a bell rung to keep time", but the units are different (not hours).

Comment: I don't think it means the face of the clock. I think it means he was counting each hour as it chimed. I do this myself: the village church is just down the road, and when I sleep badly, I notice which hours I hear and which I sleep through.

Comment: In the original version it isn't just "bells" or *campanas*, but rather *campanadas*, which is specifically the sound bells make. So yes, the bell was rung seven times. Also, the ringing of the church bells telling the time is key throughout the book, so I'd take it literally.

Comment: @Yay is campanadas plural? Does Spanish use s to pluralize like English?

Comment: If he meant that one bell was rung each hour, I think it would say "seventh".

Comment: Yes, it is, and yes, it does, and [more consistently than English](http://www.mamalisa.com/blog/a-poem-about-the-wackiness-of-the-english-language/), I'd say.

Comment: Yeah @Barmer, I think you are right, it would say "seventh bell" if per-hour ring was intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the passage has already refers to the cathedral clock, we can assume that it means seven bells rung in quick succession, which cathedral clocks often do.  This is a bit ambiguous, since it could mean the seventh bell, although I doubt it,  but both "seven bells" and "the seventh bell" in this context mean the same: 7:00.  The narrator is waiting until 7:00, when he/she has to be at the church.